# List destructor in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

I've just implemented the Linked List. It works perfectly fine but even tough I've seen notation I am unable to create working destructor on Node, that's why it's unimplemented here in code.

1. I need to implement working destructor on node
2. Destructor of List but this one is simple I will just use the destructor from Node class(but I need this one).
3. Make the List friendly to Node so I will not have to use getNext(), but I think I can
   handle it myself(not sure how, but I'll find out).

Please look at the code it is perfectly fine, just will work if you copy it.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    Node(Node* next, int wrt) {
        this->next = next;
        this->wrt = wrt;
    }

    Node(const Node& obiekt) {
        this->wrt = obiekt.wrt;
        this->next = obiekt.next;
    }
    ~Node() {}

    void show() {
        cout << this->wrt << endl;
    }

    int getWrt(){
        return this->wrt;
    }

    Node* getNext(){
        return this->next;
    }

    void setNext(Node* node){
        this->next = node;
    }

 private:
    Node* next;
    int wrt;
};

class List{
public:
    List(int wrt){
        this->root = new Node(NULL, wrt);
    }

    List(const List& obiekt){
        memcpy(&this->root,&obiekt.root,sizeof(int));
        Node* el = obiekt.root->getNext();
        Node* curr = this->root;
        Node* next;
        while(el != NULL){
            memcpy(&next,&el,sizeof(int));
            curr->setNext(next);
            curr = next;
            next = curr->getNext();
            el = el->getNext();
    /*      curr->show();
            next->show();
            el->show(); */
        }
    }

    void add(int wrt){
        Node* node = new Node(NULL, wrt);
        Node* el = this->root;
        while(el->getNext() != NULL){
            //el->show();
            el = el->getNext();
        }
        el->setNext(node);
    }

    void remove(int index){
        Node* el = this->root;
        if(index == 0){
             //deleting old one
             this->root = this->root->getNext();
        }
        else{
            int i  = 0;
            while(el != NULL && i < index - 1){
            //  el->show();
                el = el->getNext();
                i++;
            }
            if(el!=NULL){
                Node* toRem = el->getNext();
                Node* newNext = toRem->getNext();
                el->setNext(newNext);
                //deleteing old one
            }
        }
    }

    void show(){
        Node* el = this->root;
        while(el != NULL){
            el->show();
            el = el->getNext();
        }
    }

    ~List(){}

private:
    Node* root;
};

int main(){
    List* l = new List(1); //first list
    l->add(2);
    l->add(3);
    l->show();
    cout << endl;

    List* lala = new List(*l); //lala is second list created by copy cosntructor
    lala->show();
    cout << endl;

    lala->add(4);
    lala->remove(0);
    lala->show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be `memcpy`-ing `Node`s as they are not POD objects.

Comment: I would start with fixing indentation and renaming variables from `n`, `n2`, `wrt`, `lala` to names that has some meaning. And also get rid of `using namespace std;` - it's bad practice to put it at the beginning of the file like that.

Comment: No it is not homework. I try to refresh my c++.
n are commented, i'll delete them now.

Comment: @robert-kilar Think positive! You *are* refreshing your c++!

Comment: All your objects are dinamically allocated, and you are not calling `delete` anywhere. Your destructors will never run...

Comment: Another small fix, in C++ the headers are `<cstdio>` and `<cstring>` instead of `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>` (as they are called in C).

Comment: I know thah my constructors will not run I wrote explanation in introduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to start with implementing destructor of `List`. Since you dynamically allocated memory by using `new`, you should free it by using `delete`. (If you used `new[]`, it would be `delete[]`):

```
~List()
{
    Node* currentNode = this->root; // initialize current node to root
    while (currentNode)
    {
        Node* nextNode = currentNode->getNext();    // get next node
        delete currentNode;                         // delete current
        currentNode = nextNode;                     // set current to "old" next
    }
}
```

Once you have proper destructor, you should try whether your copy constructor is correct:

```
List* lala = new List(*l);
delete l; // delete list that was used to create copy, shouldn't affect copy
```

you will find out that your copy constructor is wrong and also causes your application to crash. Why? Because purpose of **copy constructor** is to create a **new** object as a copy of an existing object. Your copy constructor just copies pointers assuming `sizeof(Node*)` equal to `sizeof(int)`. It should look like this:

```
List(const List& list)
{
    // if empty list is being copied:
    if (!list.root)
    {
        this->root = NULL;
        return;
    }

    // create new root:
    this->root = new Node(NULL, list.root->getWrt());

    Node* list_currentNode = list.root;
    Node* this_currentNode = this->root;
    while (list_currentNode->getNext())
    {
        // create new successor:
        Node* newNode = new Node(NULL, list_currentNode->getNext()->getWrt());
        this_currentNode->setNext(newNode);
        this_currentNode = this_currentNode->getNext();
        list_currentNode = list_currentNode->getNext();
    }
}
```

Also your function `remove` is wrong since it "removes" reference to some Node but never frees memory where this Node resides. `delete` should be called in order to free this memory.

***"I need to implement working destructor on node"*** - No, you don't. Node itself doesn't allocate any memory, thus it shouldn't free any memory. Node shouldn't be responsible for destruction of `Node* next` nor cleaning memory where it's stored. Don't implement destructor nor copy constructor of Node. You also want to read this: [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1168156)

***"Make the List friendly to Node so I will not have to use getNext()"*** - You want to say within Node class, that `class List` is its `friend`:

```
class Node
{
    friend class List; // <-- that's it
```

Note that from these 5 headers that you include your code requires only one: `<iostream>`.
Also note that writing `using namespace std;` at the beginning of the file is considered **bad practice** since it may cause names of some of your types become ambiguous. Use it wisely within small scopes or use `std::` prefix instead.

Comment: Actually, it would be just better to define `Node` as an inner private struct in `List`. Then you can avoid using `friend`.

Comment: I really thank You for sharing that knowledge with me. By the way you've presented it to me I assume that you probably would be a good teatcher(academic). Great.

Answer (score 1):

The linked list destructor will be called either when `delete` is used with a previously allocated pointer to a linked list or when a linked list variable goes out of scope (e.g., a local variable is destroyed when returning from a function).

The destructor for the linked list should be responsible to free the memory you previously reserved for the nodes (i.e., using `add` operation). So, basically, you need to traverse the list of nodes and apply the `delete` operation on each one of them. There is a little trick: when you are about to delete a node you must be careful not to lose the pointer to the next element (when a node is deleted you cannot be sure that `next` member will still be valid).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a destructor for your Node, it should be quite simple actually.

Here it is:

```
class Node {
    private:
        int wrt;
        Node* next;
    public:
        Node(Node* next, int wrt) {
            this->next = next;
            this->wrt = wrt;
        }

        // Your desired destructor using recursion
        ~Node() {
            if ( next != NULL )
                delete next;
        }
};
```

It's that simple :)

Basically, right before the Node is deleted, if next is not empty, we delete next, which will again call the destructor of next, and if next->next is not empty, again the destructor gets called over and over.

Then in the end all Nodes get deleted.

The recursion takes care of the whole thing :)

Comment: I think this will cause a stack overflow for a big enough list due to the recursive destructor calls.